# "Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout" error

Tags: android, xml, admob

I can not fix this error for the life of me. I have looked at Google and around and no solutions have worked. My ad seems to work fine on Android 1.5 and 1.6 but above version 2 I am getting that error.

I have placed my ad inside a LinearLayout which is the first layout inside a scroll view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads" 
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="@drawable/bg_wallpaper"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:id="@+id/drillactivity"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" 
        android:layout_height="340dp">

             <com.google.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adUnitId="my id goes here"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

I am not using any code in my class for the ad. I prefer to do it via xml only.

Answer (score 3):

I had the similar warning with black screen. The problem was that there was two different apps on the device with the same AdMob id.

I removed the second app (using by mistake the same id) and the problem dissappeard.

Answer (score 3):

Using the following code, I fixed this error.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="320dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:gravity="center"
ads:adUnitId="my id goes here"
ads:adSize="BANNER"
ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

I haven't got any specific reason of this error, It may not work in every case.

Comment: What does loadAdOnCreate do?  In my case it caused the following warning: "loadAd called while the ad is already loading, so aborting."

Comment: loadAdOnCreate will load ad in onCreate. So you don't have to send a ad request separately in the onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Linear/Relative layout in the xml, which you are infalting in your activity. and then set the activity as listener to adView. 
Like :

```
googleAdView = new AdView(Activity,AdSize.IAB_BANNER, ADMOB_SITE_ID);
googleAdView.setAdListener(Activity);
com.google.ads.AdRequest request = new com.google.ads.AdRequest();
this.adMobLayout.removeAllViews();
this.adMobLayout.addView(googleAdView);
googleAdView.loadAd(request);
```

Here adMobLayout is the layout which you have declared in the xml layout.